# Replacing specified elements in a list (python), using an index array - error message

Tags: python, arrays, indexing

I am trying to create a large list to later add in to a panda dataframe, with the elements of this list corresponding to the conditions of the data in that row (i.e. basal condition, +some drug ... etc).

These conditions come in blocks; i.e. the first 500 rows (corresponding to first 500 frames of imaging data) correspond to basal conditions (so each element should be 'basal'), the next 500 with some drug added, and so on.

The precise size of each of these blocks, and the first row of the block, varies from experiment to experiment, so the code should ideally be able to generate these blocks based on the numbers I input specifying the time of different conditions for each experiment

To do this I am first generating a list of 'basal' repeated according to the total number of rows, then using the timing variables signifying the start of each condition to overwrite every entry from this index to the end of the list with the next condition. Code is:

epochs = ['basal'] * frames

```
if ttx == True:
    ttx_epoch = np.arange(ttx_t*freq,frames,1, dtype=int)
    epochs[ttx_epoch] = 'TTX'
if lo_k == True:
    lok_epoch = np.arange(lo_k_t*freq,frames,1, dtype=int)
    epochs[lok_epoch] = 'Low K'
if hi_k == True:
    hik_epoch = np.arange(hi_k_t*freq,frames,1, dtype=int)
    print(hik_epoch)
    epochs[hik_epoch] = 'High K'
```

when I attempt to run I get the error message:

TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

Despite specifying the type of the arange index array as int

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Comment: You should better phrase your question, if you can let other people easily reproduce your error, it could help. I find myself struggling trying to understand what you want to do.

Comment: If I want to create a big list, i'd to something like this: `import itertools` first and `list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([['Basal'] * x, ['Drug'] * y]))`, where `x` and `y` are integers

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In a simplified set up where I had 10 frames of imaging data, each representing 1 second samples, lets say the first 4 seconds corresponded to basal conditions, and the rest of the data was with a drug (TTX) applied. I would want to generate a list looking like:

[ 'basal' , 'basal',  'basal',  'basal', 'TTX', 'TTX',  'TTX',  'TTX',  'TTX',  'TTX']

with the only input variables being '4' seconds of basal condition, and '4' seconds as the start of the TTX condition (until the end of the experiment).

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: By finding alternate way

I realised the whole task was unecessary, as I could achieve the desired result by specifying a range to index into the dataframe itself (rather than generate an array to then insert into the dataframe.